# Bind unimputed data to imputed dataset in R (mice)

Tags: r, mice

I've created a multiple imputed data set with mice (50 imputations). I've only imputed certain variables and want to be able to add the rest of the variables to the imputed data set. I do not include the variables in the imputation phase because the data set contains quite a few variables (3000+), and because the data set will be appended with more variables in the future.

My current solution is this:

```
#midata is the imputed mids object
#add_data is a data frame with the unimputed variables i wish to add to the imputed dataset.
  fulldata <- complete(midata, include = T, action = 'long')
  imputs <- 50
  L <- lapply(0:imputs, function(x) merge(fulldata[which(fulldata[1] == x),],add_data, by = id))
  merged_dataset <- do.call("rbind", L)
```

This approach takes quite some time and fails occasionally, probably because of internal memory issues.
Does anyone know of a better way to append new variables to an already imputed data set?

Comment: I think you might be better off on an R-specific site like R-help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be easier than i thought. It was built in to the cbind.mids function.

```
cbind.mids(midata, data.frame(add_data))
```

seems to do the trick as long as the data frame is sorted the same way the mids object is.